# Are any Star Wars materials written from the perspective of the droids?

Tags: star-wars, droids, literary-analysis

I know that Lucas said he framed the story in the original trilogy around R2-D2 and C-3PO, based on the peasant characters being at the center of the action in Kurosawa's *The Hidden Fortress*.

#### But have any books or other media been written from the perspective of the droids?  I am particularly interested in any insights into what R2 makes of the events in which he plays a part.

*Note:  The higher the level of canon, present or past, the better, but anything along these lines will do.*

Comment: The novelisations contain *elements* of first-person narrative from the perspectives of **all** of the main characters including the droids.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids

Comment: @Richard Gimme something I can upvote so you get rep!

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to do the write-up

Comment: @Richard - are you talking about animated film, or DH comic?

Comment: I have a strong memory of a series of scenes where a battle droid has slowly gained self awareness after it's many battles, and it converses with...C3PO? Don't have a source though; it's been years since I read any EU, and it's definitely legends by now...

Comment: @DVK - I was referring to the campy TV show rather than the comics.

Comment: @Richard - oups, too late, I listed all three. Just in case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. **[LEGO Star Wars: Droid Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars:_Droid_Tales)**:

   > will tell the entire Star Wars saga – in the medium of Lego – from the perspective of R2-D2 and C-3PO, following the pair as they witness some of the most memorable (or in the case of the prequels, regrettably unforgettable) moments in the history of the Skywalker family album and the Star Wars galaxy.
   >
   > The new five-part series will air on Disney XD and kicks off just after the victory celebration in the Ewok village on Endor at the end of *Return of The Jedi*, with R2 and 3PO "accidentally kidnapped" and taken on a new hop around the galaxy. ([source](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-03-03/lego-and-disney-to-retell-entire-star-wars-saga-from-r2-d2-and-c-3pos-perspective))
2. ***Star Wars Special: C-3PO #1***, an upcoming Marvel C-3PO comic, [according to Starwars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-special-c-3po-1):

   > Today, Marvel announced , a new story from the *Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens* publishing program coming in December. Reuniting the acclaimed and award-winning writer and artist team of James Robinson and Tony Harris for the first time in nearly two decades, the tale follows “golden rod” on a solo adventure leading up to his appearance in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* — and reveals what led to this change in appearance.
3. "Dark Nest" trilogy book "**The Joiner King**" had what probably counts.

   It had a scene of Anakin Skywalker and Padme - as well a later discussions of Anakin between Obi-Wan and Padme - as seen and recorded by R2-D2.

   This one is kind of iffy since it's basically a holorecording of what happened in the Prequels.
4. [***Star Wars: Droids***](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Droids:_The_Protocol_Offensive) from DC Comics is sometimes listed in this class.

   However, it's only true *from a certain point of view* - being a comic, it's hard to definitively declare that it's told from *anyone's* perspective, other than cartoonist's. But there are scenes where R2-D2 and C-3PO alone talking, so presumably that counts, e.g. this one from *"Protocol Offensive"*:

   [image]
5. ***[Star Wars Animated Adventures: Droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Animated_Adventures:_Droids)***

   This was a 2004 DVD release of earlier 1985/6 TV series ***["Star Wars: Droids: The Adventures of R2-D2 and C-3PO"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids:_The_Adventures_of_R2-D2_and_C-3PO)***. (Hat/tip: Richard's comment)

   [image]
6. [***Star Wars: Droids***](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids_%28Marvel%29) comics series from Marvel.

   NOT to be confused with #4 above (same-named comics from Dark Horse) which was wholly independent

   Also NOT to be confused with #5 above (same-named animated TV series from the same people who brought you Ewok Adventures) - however, the Marvel comics are closely related to TV series, being somewhat based on TV show ("somewhat" is well-deserved - see the Wookieepedia link for extremely confusing details).

   [image]
7. ***[The Droids Re-animated](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Droids_Re-Animated)*** was a series of posts on [Star Wars Blog](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-droids-re-animated-part-1), based on #4, #5 and #6 above (both DH and Marvel comics and TV series), as well as a couple of other sources and original canon material.
8. *Beaumont Studios* strips [*Sabotaged Droid*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sabotaged_Droid) and [*Troublesome Outing*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Troublesome_Outing) were published in Spanish under *MyCompic* imprint.
   They are quite similar to Dark Horse comics comics above and were included in canon by having mentions in "The Droids Re-animated" from #7.

Comment: I do believe you've covered everything.

Comment: There was at least one *SW: The Clone Wars* arc where C-3PO and R2-D2 were the protagonists.

Comment: Hilariously, the Shakespeare's Star Wars series does a fairly good job of this for the original trilogy. Everyone gets asides including the droids, the Wampa, and the giant space slug. Obviously not canon but could be interesting.

Comment: @RogueJedi - problem is, protagonist doesn't necessarily mean perspective. LitCrit is HARD (the proper scholarly kind, not the postmodernist junk)

Answer (score 5):

Stay tuned - there is a new C-3PO one-off comic in February that will explain his new red arm. POV uncertain at this time but that might be an answer.

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Special:_C-3PO_1

[image]

Comment: Why red arm? Did Tony tune him up?

Comment: @PTwr- You'll have to wait until February to find out.

Comment: Wait... are those... lense flares?

Answer (score 2):

There was a comic written a while ago in the tales comics that was told from the perspective of the droid with the bad motivator.  Skippy the Jedi droid.